# Why does port redirection via IPtables for a second DNS resolver on the same server not work?

Tags: iptables, bind, unbound

I have a Raspberry Pi that is running Bind9 as an authoritative DNS server for a local zone. Every other DNS requests are forwarded to a public DNS server. So Bind9 is listening on port `53` at address `192.168.1.254`.

Now I want to install Unbound on this Raspberry Pi to provide "DNS over TLS". Because you can't have two different resolvers listening on the same port (`53`), I thought that I could solve this with a second IP address and port forwarding.

So I configured unbound to listen at `192.168.1.2:1053`. DNS queries to this port and address are answered correctly. Over IPtables I installed the following rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dst 192.168.1.2 --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1053
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dst 192.168.1.2 --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1053
```

Now DNS queries to `192.168.1.2` and port `53` are not answered because of a timeout at the client side.

With IPtables I can determine that the rules are applied correctly but I didn't get an answer. Why?

Comment: Why not simply do [DNS over TLS in BIND](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01386)?

Comment: Don't want to do "DNS over TLS" for all clients on the network and bind9 is only able to do it with stunnel.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this: In the case I described above, simple port forwarding isn't enough. The following does the trick:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 --dst 192.168.1.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:1053
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 --dst 192.168.1.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:1053
```

Maybe there are other solutions but this is what works fine for me.

Comment: This is a good answer!